# Compilation Error- Array of byte initialization

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, c#-4.0

I am working on a VB project that needs to be transformed to c#.
 I came across the below code which do is doesn't seem to be valid with c# 
the compiler isn't recognizing  **&H21,&H43....**

Can some one explain to me what do these codes mean and what is there equivalent in c#

```
Dim rgbIV As Byte() = New Byte() {&H21, &H43, &H56, &H87, &H10,&HFD,&HEA}
```

Comment: Btw, in VB.NET you can shorten it: `Dim rgbIV As Byte() = {&H21, &H43, &H56, &H87, &H10, &HFD, &HEA}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are hexadecimal literal values.  Here's what you want to do in C#:

```
var rgbIV = new Byte[] {0x21, 0x43, 0x56, 0x87, 0x10, 0xFD, 0xEA};
```